# View not showing?

Tags: ios, animation, view, transition

In my app when I am switching views with an animation using UIView animations, it does not show anything, the view is black but I know my method is getting called. I have NSLogged where the view is and I printed the results and posted them below.

My code is below, but does anyone see anything that is wrong?

```
-(void)changeView2ToView3 {
    NSLog(@"Before, frame= %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view3.view.frame));

    [view2.view.superview addSubview:view3.view];
    [view3.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kHeight, kWidth, kHeight)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 
                     animations:^{
                         [view3.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight)];  
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [view2.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
    NSLog(@"Before, frame= %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view3.view.frame));
}
```

kHeight and kWidth are the height and width of the screen and they are never 0 or nil.

Also this is what is printed from the console:

```
2012-02-02 15:58:30.449 App[27578:707] Before, frame= {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
2012-02-02 15:58:30.452 App[27578:707] Before, frame= {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
2012-02-02 15:58:36.234 App[27578:707] Before, frame= {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
2012-02-02 15:58:36.237 App[27578:707] Before, frame= {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar thing is happening to me with an app I'm working on. I think what's wrong with yours is that you didn't specify a height or width, they are both 0? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: kWidth and kHeight are the width and height of the screen and they are not 0 or nil so thats not the issue :/